# Subdivide lagrange interpolated curve

Tags: graphics, geometry, 2d, interpolation, curve

I'm looking for a way to subdivide a curve, generated by Lagrange interpolation.

Let's say I have a curve defined by c1,c2,c3 control points, and I want to divide it somewhere between c1 and c2 with d1 (d1 is a point that's on the curve between c1 and c2).

As a result I'm expecting 2 sets of control points, defining 2 curves that are equivalent (or  very close) to the original curve. The picture below illustrates what I mean, the resulting 2 curves are moved apart for better visual representation only (dc1 and dc2 are newly created control points).
[image]

Is it possible to calculate the necessary control points for the 2 new lagrange curves with some formula, or the best I can do is to approximate?
(I could interpolate the curve with short straight lines with a given precision, subdivide the created polyline at d1, and call it a day, but I'm hoping there is a formula for this, or at least a better algorithm than the one I'm suggesting here)

**Clarification**: I'm looking for a solution for 2D, like here: https://cindyjs.org/examples/25_Lagrange.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lagrange polynomial for three points is the only quadratic polynomial through these points.

So you can get any point inside left part and any point inside right part and recalculate two Lagrange polynomials - but they **will be similar** to each other and to initial polynomial.

I mean there is no sense in subdivision at all.

BTW, how are you going to use these curves?

Comment: I'm using these curves in a drawing software. I want the user to be able to split the curve at any given point, and be able to move the resulting curves separately.

If we stick with the example above, if user splits at d1 I'll have 2 sets of control points --> [c1, d1] and [d1, c2, c3]. If I use these points for generating 2 new Lagrange curves, the result won't be similar to the original curve (for example c1,d1 would now be a straight line, but originally it was on a quadratic surface --> guessing I need to insert new control points somewhere in this case (dc1 on picture)

Comment: Perhaps Bezier curves might be better choice for drawing and subdivision.

Comment: If you put point dc1 on  the curve in the lower part, then lower curve piece, then c1,dc1, d1 shoud give the same curve when you continue it

Comment: The curve types are given, I can't switch to Bezier's, it would cause regression :\

Comment: yes, but I need to automatically calculate the position of dc1, so I need a formula for that.

Comment: Make  `(c1.x+d1.x)/2` value and calculate corresponding Y for this X from langrange formula

Comment: Hmm, I probably wasn't accurate enough with the description. By lagrange curves, I meant 2D curves like here. https://cindyjs.org/examples/25_Lagrange.html

Inserting a point halfway on the curve (between c1 and d1) won't always result in the same curve shape (try moving a point on the curve in the link above, the whole curve shape will change, even you are moving a control point on the original curve shape)

Comment: OK, I meant usual Lagrange interpolation y=f(x), here is parameteric one y=f(t),x=f(t), with parametrization over point number (ts=1..n in source code). If you can find point at some fractional t (say t=0.5), insert this point into `ts` list, recalculate `f(t,k)` - I expect you'll get similar curve (I'm not sure because polynomial degree rises)